# what is the equivalent component in android like uiindicator in iphone

Tags: iphone, android

can anybody tell what is the equivalent component in android like uiindicator in iphone give example

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In activity java class:

```
protected void startProgress() {
    ProgressBar pbSpinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.activity_progress_bar);    
    pbSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
}

protected void stopProgress() {
    ProgressBar pbSpinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.activity_progress_bar);
    pbSpinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

And in layout xml file you can add progress bar:

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/activity_progress_bar"              
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true">            
</ProgressBar>
```